# Placing item on center of a div without blocking the content on the sides - Tumblr

Tags: html, css

I would like to place a (featured) tag line on the center of a div where the post note count is on the left and the tumblr like-reblog buttons are on the right.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAkTi.jpg

**The problem**: since the tag line div is over these, it's blocking the ability to click on them.

The css:

```
.post_post {
    width: 472px;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    padding:12px 14px 10px 14px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    top: 0px!important;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.tags {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    left: 0px!important;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
.tags a {
    background-color:;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
}

.tags a.news {
    background-color: {color:News Tag};
    display: inline!important;
}

.tags a.featured {
    background-color: {color:Featured Tag};
    display: inline!important;
}

.tags a.photos {
    background-color: {color:Photos Tag};
    display: inline!important;
}
```

HTML:

> ```
> <div class="post_post">
>         <a href="{permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
>
>         {block:HasTags}
>         <span class="tags">
>             {block:Tags}
>             <a href="{TagURL}" class="{Tag}">{Tag}</a> 
>             {/block:Tags}
>         </span>
>         {/block:HasTags}
>
>         <ul class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
>             <li>{ReblogButton size="16" color="grey"}</li>
>             <li>{LikeButton size="16" color="grey"}</li>
>         </ul>
> </div>
> ```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but this was the only way I could get the div on the center no matter how many tags are being displayed.

Comment: I can't see your example right now, but from your description I feel that setting your z-index to something higher should work.

Comment: @Jhecht well I tried changing the z-index for the note count link and the buttons to a higher one but it didn't work.

Comment: What is your HTML for this so that I can work on it in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Jhecht sure I just added it to the post

Comment: Just sort of fiddling around with your CSS and such, why is it that you have the a elements of an element with class "tags" hidden, if these are the tags for the post?

Comment: Also, on a white background, you've got your text set to white. which, may be a thing on your actual webpage.

Comment: @Jhecht Oh, it's because I only display 3 featured tags and set a different style for each one. Just added the rest of the css maybe you will now understand what I'm doing

Comment: @Jhecht are you still unable to see the example picture? I could upload it somewhere else

Comment: I can see the picture fine, the issue is coming about that I don't see any indication that the links are being blocked.

Comment: @Jhecht because I set a 500px width for the div.tags to center it, if the div.tags background was red, it would block the view of the note count and like-reblog buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am by no means a CSS master as I work mostly with back-end coding, but here are a few things I noticed about your CSS/HTML code.

1. You use `id="tags"`, but what I assume is your tags CSS definition is missing the `#` operator. Also, if this is going to be repeated for each post on your website (looks like tumblr?), the `id="tags"` needs to turn into `class="tags"`. Remember, an ID is UNIQUE (only 1), classes are not.
2. This line in what I assume is your `#tags a` definition : `display: none;' hides the links. Not sure why it's there, but I deleted it.
3. I am assuming that this isn't meant to be the entire div used for the contents of the post, just the footer bar at the bottom.

I've made a solution, you can see it at [This Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gDehC). Now, I don't have access to the CSS styles that give the colors for things like the news tag or such. I used a `column-count` css attribute with some creative text-align. If I were doing this project, this is **not** how I would do this, but it gave the quickest way for a solution that didn't look awful or involve me totally rewriting both your HTML and CSS.

If you would like, I could rewrite the HTML and CSS for you how I would do it and show you that.

### General Tip

When I do have to deal with CSS, I follow this simple rule: Focus on 1 thing at a time. It is much easier to get all the little things going than it is to try and code the whole page the first time around.

### EDIT

Here's [Another Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gDehC) that shows how I would go about this, more or less. Without making the entirety of the webpage. There may be some styles that conflict. You'll see that I made it so that the second post has no tags, at least on my browser it displays correctly.

Comment: 1) I changed the ID to class because the # would mess up the post (and I forgot to edit the html). 2) My theme only displays 3 chosen featured tags on the index page, that's why there's a display: none property, so the tags that are not my 3 featured tags don't show up. 3) Yes it's all part of post footer (.post_post), I just added the css to the post. // Your solution seems like a nice way to fix it but it messed up the style of my post footer. Example: http://i.imgur.com/rexvToK.jpg, it also messes up when a post doesn't have any tag to display. Example: http://i.imgur.com/2IV5rnB.jpg

Comment: I didn't have access to all of that. Use what you will from the code pen.

Comment: I just edited my previous answer and added a few example pics. By the way, you are free to rewrite the css and html for a proper solution! :D

Comment: ignore the first example of my first answer, I just noticed that I didn't add the <div> to the note-count text, it now looks great but it still messes up when the post doesn't have tags to display

Comment: I've updated the code pen. In the span tag that sits in the middle, I just added a &nbsp; so that browsers remember to display that span.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was on a trip. I just tried your new solution and it worked perfectly! Thank you.